# OnDeviceReady not firing in iOS after upgrade to Cordova

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

Someone asked a similar question and there are no good answers. So I thought I would help out...

I struggled with it for over two weeks and there was no easy way to find this. Apparently,you have to use the right Cordova js version with the Cordova iOS installation. It is not documented or displayed anywhere...but if you go into your cordova setup (wherever they are located on your hard drive), you can see the Cordova js file. Typically in the users/shared/cordova/framework/cordova.framework/www folder. Then copy the js file into your project, change references and that should do it.

Comment: What is it a Question or an answer ?